# jpa datetime compare eclipselink

Tags: date, jpa, compare

probably this is a simple question but it should work already in my opinion. I want to set status on every Auction where expDate is less than current date. expDate is DATETIME in database. Actually it doesn't work. Could you help please? 
I've also tried with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
 Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Auction e SET e.status = 0 WHERE e.expDate < :today");
        query.setParameter("today", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

edit:

```
  Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Auction e SET e.status = 0 WHERE e.status = 1");
```

that doesnt work too. I use: `@PersistenceContext()
    EntityManager entityManager;`
It seems that the update query isn't executed.

Comment: Did you call query.executeUpdate();?  createQuery only gives you a query object which you can then use to add hints etc before executing.

Comment: I cant use executeUpdate in non-transactional entityManager got from PersistantContext

Comment: yes, it requires a transaction.  If you are not using JTA, wrap your changes in em.getTransaction().begin(); em.getTransaction().commit(); calls, otherwise you will need to wrap your method in a transaction or look it up from the container to start it.

Comment: Great.  There are many tutorials for how to handle this for your server/transaction environment.  If you are having problems and need help, try to be more descriptive and show how you might have tried to help yourself already.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an ugly workaround. I got all auctions, then i got all expired auctions in for loop and finally merged expired autions. Last thing was getting auctions again to return them. I had to use transaction despite of using JTA. But it had to be UserTransation which is unclear to me. Anyone can explain me why?

```
@Resource
    UserTransaction ut;

    public List<Auction> getAuctionList() throws Exception {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Auction e WHERE e.status=1");
        query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
        auctionList = (List<Auction>) query.getResultList();
        for (Auction a : auctionList) {
            Date today = new Date();
            System.out.println("compare: " + a.getExpDate() + " and " + today);
            if (a.getExpDate().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) {
                a.setStatus("0");
                ut.begin();
                entityManager.merge(a);
                ut.commit();
            }
        }
        Query newQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Auction e WHERE e.status=1");
        newQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
        auctionList = (List<Auction>) newQuery.getResultList();
        return auctionList;
    }
```

Comment: You are having the container inject a transaction - it falls under the look up the transaction from the container part of my earlier comment.    JTA is set of api, and UserTransaction one of the included interfaces.  So you are getting a resource from your container, starting the transaction. Your JPA is then allowed to use the transaction.  You are missing a portion though, as you have not called em.joinTransaction() after the ut.begin() call.  This is required to associate the existing EM to the started transaction.  It may work now, but is not expected to work in the future.